# typeMismatch.java.util.List when trying to set a list

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to set a `List<Long>` to an Java object.

The set function is:

```
ResponseEntity<String> response = bcInsertService.addNewClip(new PrmBcClipInsert()
    .setTags(Arrays.asList(new Long[]{5L, 3L}))
);
```

And the object is

```
public class PrmBcClipInsert implements Serializable {

    @ApiModelProperty(required = true)
    private List<Long> tags;

    public List<Long> getTags() {
        return tags;
    }

    public PrmBcClipInsert setTags(List<Long> tags) {
        this.tags = tags;
        return this;
    }
}
```

This is BcInsertService:

```
public class BcInsertService extends RestTemplate {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BcInsertService.class);

    public ResponseEntity<String> addNewClip(PrmBcClipInsert prmBcClipInsert) {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
        MultiValueMap<String, Object> map= new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> request = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>>(prmBcClipInsert.getParameters(), headers);

        ParameterizedTypeReference<StandardResponse> typeRef = new ParameterizedTypeReference<StandardResponse>() {};
        ResponseEntity<String> response = this.postForEntity( "http://localhost:8080/bc/add-clip", request , String.class );
        log.info(response.toString());
        return response;
    }

}
```

And it returns an error:

> Field error in object 'prmBcClipInsert' on field 'tags': rejected
>   value [[5,3]]; codes
>   [typeMismatch.prmBcClipInsert.tags,typeMismatch.tags,typeMismatch.java.util.List,typeMismatch];
>   arguments
>   [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable:
>   codes [prmBcClipInsert.tags,tags]; arguments []; default message
>   [tags]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type
>   'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.List' for property
>   'tags'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input
>   string: "[5,3]"]

Why the method doesn't accept a list even though it says that it accepts a list?

Comment: *Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.List' for property 'tags'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "[5,3]"* - My guess is that this error is happening while deserializing. You are passing a string instead of an array/list.

Comment: Side note: creating an anonymous subclass just to set a field is ugly, and completely necessary. Why not just use `addNewClip(new PrmBcClipInsert().setTags(Arrays.asList(5L, 3L)));`? Isn't that the whole point of returning `this`from setTags()?

Comment: Please include the full stacktrace.

Comment: @StephenC there is no exception, only the error message.

Comment: I think we need a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) then.

Comment: Can you make sure not to use `{{...}}` initialization and pass it an object initiated normally? See if that helps

Comment: @TarunLalwani unfortunately it didn't help.

Comment: @ilhan, if you can provide a minimal git repo, it would be easier to help. Currently, it's not easy to understand what could be wrong here

Comment: Hello @ilhan can you share some more code so that we can get more idea

Comment: The error says, it is something related to `DefaultMessageSourceResolvable` class. How is this class being used with `MessageSourceResolvable`?

Comment: @pkgajulapalli this is a 2 module Spring Application. `DefaultMessageSourceResolvable` and `MessageSourceResolvable` must be something to do with Spring internals.

Comment: @ilhan, `DefaultMessageSourceResolvable` is used when you're using `Locale`. Keep a debugger in `setTags` method and observer which method is invoking it.

Comment: when does this exception show up? at the startup of your application?

Comment: There is no `getParameters()` method in your posted `PrmBcClipInsert` class, so this code is not the code producing the posted error.

Comment: also Multivalue Map or typeRef variables are not used at all

Comment: Share the full stack trace and also share getter code prmBcClipInsert.getParameters() so that we can help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was able to recreate your error case using a form validation. You are *probably* trying to pass a form data that is `[5, 3]` for the `tags` variable with type `List<Long>`, but passing with brackets break that structure, the value ought to be `5, 3`...

So what I've done is;

1. Create a dummy controller using your input;

   ```
   @Controller
   public class TestController {

       @PostMapping
       public ModelAndView test(@Validated @ModelAttribute final PrmBcClipInsert prmBcClipInsert, final BindingResult bindingResult) {
           final ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
           System.out.println(prmBcClipInsert.getTags());
           modelAndView.setViewName("test");
           return modelAndView;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Pass the form with `tags=[5,3]`, and get the following error in `BindingResult`;

   > org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
   >   Field error in object 'prmBcClipInsert' on field 'tags': rejected
   >   value [[5, 3]]; codes
   >   [typeMismatch.prmBcClipInsert.tags,typeMismatch.tags,typeMismatch.java.util.List,typeMismatch];
   >   arguments
   >   [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable:
   >   codes [prmBcClipInsert.tags,tags]; arguments []; default message
   >   [tags]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type
   >   'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.List' for property
   >   'tags'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input
   >   string: "[5,3]"]

   Which is the identical error that you were getting... So I presume either you get this `PrmBcClipInsert` as a form input like in my example, or you are trying to do a similar binding in some other part of your code...
3. Pass the form with `tags=5,3`, *no error*...

---

There can be a custom converter to support for passing said array input with brackets in binding logic with something like;

```
@Component
public class LongListConverter implements Converter<String, List<Long>> {

    @Override
    public List<Long> convert(String source) {
        return Arrays.stream(StringUtils.strip(source, "[]").split(","))
                .map(StringUtils::strip)
                .map(Long::new)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

With this, both `5, 3` & `[5, 3]` can be supplied as value of `tags` variable.

Comment: We have moved to send the data with JSON and send the file separately. But I'm accepting your answer since passing tags=5,3 solves the problem. I think alternative answer would be to write a custom converter for the list which implements `ConverterFactory` but for a `List` like https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html however Spring's documentation is very weak.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is a converter here. Create a List<>String converter like below (refactor the below example in your code):

```
@Converter
public class StringListConverter implements AttributeConverter<List<String>, String> {
    private static final String SPLIT_CHAR = ";";

    // Go nuts on List to string here...

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(List<String> stringList) {
        return String.join(SPLIT_CHAR, stringList.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> convertToEntityAttribute(String string) {
        return Arrays.asList(string.split(SPLIT_CHAR));
    }
}
```

Try it and share the outcome.